# copy array of pointers and print the copy

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to copy a pointers of arrays and print the values from the copied array, but I got a Segmentation fault.

```
void kosomo(char * test[10]) {
        int j=0;
        char * test2[10];
        while (test[j] != NULL) {
                test2[j]=&test[j]; // test[j] is the string, so with & it's the address
                j++;
        }

        printf("%d ",*test2[0]); // trying to do * in order to print the string
}


int main() {
        char * test[] = {"abc","def",NULL};

        kosomo(test);
}
```

Comment: `test[j]` is a `char *`. `&test[j]` is a `char **`. You're trying to assign it to a variable of type `char *`. Your compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: `test2[j]=&test[j];` --> `test2[j]=test[j];`, `printf("%d ",*test2[0]);` --> `printf("%s ", test2[0]);`

Comment: You're confusing strings and an array of pointers to char. E.g., you start with an array of three strings (the `[10]` in your parameter definition is unnecessary and illogical), then try to print just one of those? It's unclear what precisely you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try if this program can help you. I assume that you want to print the whole array of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void kosomo(char *test[10]) {
    int j = 0;
    char *test2[10];
    while (test[j] != NULL) {
        test2[j] = test[j]; 
        j++;
    }
    test2[j] = NULL;
    j=0;
    while (test2[j] != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", test2[j]);
        j++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *test[] = {"abc", "def", NULL};
    kosomo(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
abc def
```